# Is it possible to send emails directly to a python script?

Tags: python, email

so I want to be able to receive an email directly to a python script, which I will then take select parts out of and display. is this possible?

Comment: You can send emails to some inbox and have your Python script retrieve and manipulate them.

Comment: This depends on the mail server software. They usually provide a way for an email address to run a program, but the specifics depend on the server. This assumes you're running your own mailserver. If you're using a third-party mail service, you'll have to do what @PM77-1 suggests.

Comment: @barmar how do i get my own mailserver to do as you suggest?

Comment: You rent a server from a service provider.

Comment: could i host my own somehow?

Comment: You can also host your own python SMTP server if that is what you want https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html

Comment: thank you! ill do some research on that